# How do I install and apply a theme for CairoDock?

Tags: themes, cairo-dock

I just downloaded an OS X theme for CairoDock. I have already extracted it and put it in my documents folder (just so I know where it is). I am completely clueless on how to apply it. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the folder where you have downloaded the tarball with the theme. **Do not extract it.**

Then go to the Cairo Dock settings : right click on a dock > `Cairo-Dock` > `Configure` (first option). Once the configuration window is opened, go to the `Themes` tab (the last one) > `Load a theme` (first tab in the second of of tabs). On this tab there is a line which offers to drag and drop the tarball. So drag and drop your tarball for its folder to the text entry at the end of the line. You can also click on `Open` and select the tarball in the dialog window. Once you do it, click on `Apply` at the bottom of the window and your theme will be installed.

You can also install the themes which are on the list at the left side of the tab by selecting the theme and then click on *Apply* at the bottom.

For further informations, you can refer to these web pages :

- Cairo-Dock themes' French wiki page : http://glx-dock.org/ww_page.php?p=Gestion%20des%20th%C3%A8mes&lang=fr **(fr)**
- Overview of Cairo-Dock themes : http://glx-dock.org/ww_page.php?p=Our%20Themes%20(an%20overview)&lang=en **(en)** or http://glx-dock.org/ww_page.php?p=Nos%20th%C3%A8mes&lang=fr **(fr)**